# Why are TS circular references allowed for object type defs

Tags: typescript, types, circular-reference

Why is this type valid:

```js
export type CircularObj = { [key: string]: CircularObj }
```

but this type is not:

```
export type CircularRecord = Record<string, CircularRecord>
```

I am getting the error `TS2456: Type alias 'CircularRecord' circularly references itself.` for CircularRecord, but not for CircularObj, and I am wondering why?

I am using typescript version 4.1.6

Comment: See [ms/TS#41164](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41164) and the answers to the linked questions